# codeigniter uri repeating after second self-call to controller

Tags: php, codeigniter

I ported some editing scripts that call thenself repaetedly to CI. They work fine the first time, but not the second time. I saw it was the URI that kept growing.

After trying to find errors in my script, or the fact I placed them in subfolder, etc, I 
found that it had nothing to do with that.

I set up this basic test:
CONTROLLER test_edit does nothing but getting  url-string:

```
  index() 
  {   
      $data['uri_string']=uri_string(); 
      $this->load->view('test_edit',$data);
   }

   index2() 
   {  
      $data['uri_string']=uri_string(); 
      $this->load->view('test_edit',$data);
   }
```

VIEW test_edit shows nothing but url-string and links to CONTROLLER:

```
  <p>URI=<?=$uri_string ?></p>;
  <p><a href="test_edit">test_edit</a></p>;
  <p><a href="test_edit/index2">test_edit/index2</a></p>;
```

This result in
URI=
After 1st click on 1st link
URI=test_edit/index
After 2nd click on 1st link
URI=**test_edit/test_edit/index**  etc. 
Click on second link will then (obviously) give 404 error.

My question:
- WTF causes this??? Why is URI not refreshed each call (cache?), or what adds segments: browser, router-class?

NB: Dont give me sjit about using base_url, the whole point of URI-translation is NOT using absolute standard URL's or absolute paths. I know how to work around this, but I would like not having to do so. I want to understand.

Comment: NB: Sorry about formatting. 1st POST in SO, and to busy getting used to format to correct my Anglish.

Comment: perhaps wrong `$config['base_url']` (do not forget about the slash that is needed in the end eg. `http://localhost/project/`)

Comment: This post needs some serious editing, even if just for the code.

Answer (score 1):

Declare the `<a> tags` like this:

```
<a href="<?=base_url('test_edit/index2')?>">test_edit/index2</a>
```

Instead of:

```
<a href="test_edit/index2">test_edit/index2</a>
```

If not using `base_url()` then use `anchor()` of `CI`:

```
anchor('string_path', 'title');
```

Comment: @user2787967 being rude to people that are trying to help you is NOT A GOOD WAY TO GET PEOPLE TO HELP YOU. jfc

Comment: you should really consider using `base_url('')` everywhere, your links in question are "retarded".